# webpack require files and give it a alias

Tags: webpack, babeljs

i am trying to require an javascript file that is not a node module in webpack.

I do currently have it like this:

```js
   var jqx = require("./../../../lib/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js");
```

I need it to be available in a global variable jqx. Just like jquery has the $.

It is not currently working and i do get the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jqx' of undefined